# OnReceive in BroacdcastReceiver return intent with extra but can't extract

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver

**PROBLEM**

I have no idea why logcat give me a NPE because the intent is not null and has extra in onReceive()
so, please help me find out and guide me somethings.

**NOTE**

1. I have multiple broadcast receiver in this project.
2. I register them with Pending Intent with unique ID.

**Logcat (Prove that it has extra along with)**

```
10-19 06:10:32.587  31593-31593/com.bis.prototype.airdroid E/BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode﹕ Intent { flg=0x14 cmp=com.bis.prototype.airdroid/.BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode (has extras) }
```

**BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode.class**

```
public class BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Log.e("BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode", String.valueOf(intent));
        String slot = intent.getExtras().getString("NODE_SLOT");
        Log.e("BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode", slot); // NPE ON THIS LINE

        Intent calibrateIntent = new Intent(context, Service_MQTTPush.class);
        calibrateIntent.putExtra("CALIBRATE_MODE",true);
        calibrateIntent.putExtra("NODE_SLOT", slot);
        context.startService(calibrateIntent);
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.bis.prototype.airdroid.BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:232)
        at com.bis.prototype.airdroid.BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode.onReceive(BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode.java:17)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2469)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code that I register my broadcast**

```
public static void registerAlarm_calibrateMode(Context context){

        for (int i = 0; i < NODE_SLOT.length; i++) {

            Log.e("registerAlarm_calibrateMode", NODE_SLOT[i]+" :: "+getNodeSerial(context,NODE_SLOT[i]));

            if (!getNodeSerial(context,NODE_SLOT[i]).equals("null")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode.class);
                Log.e("registerAlarm_calibrateMode", "putExtra-->"+NODE_SLOT[i]);
                intent.putExtra("NODE_SLOT", NODE_SLOT[i]);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        context,
                        GET_NODE_BROADCAST_ID_FOR_CALIBRATE_MODE[getNodeID(NODE_SLOT[i])],
                        intent,
                        Intent.FILL_IN_DATA
                );
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                now.add(Calendar.MINUTE,1);

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
                } else {
                    alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,now.getTimeInMillis(),pi);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**XML MANIFEST**

```
    <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiver_SleepMode"/>
    <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiver_Location"/>
    <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode"/>
    <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiver_TempLog"/>
```

Comment: You can use `intent.getExtras().keySet()` and `intent.getExtras().get(key)` to list all the extras included in your intent. That should help you verify whether the intent really has a NODE_SLOT like you wanted.

Comment: That would be help.. I try

Comment: Also, check the usage of Intent.FILL_IN_DATA. It's possible that the intent data has been overwritten before being delivered back to the activity.

Comment: @MikeLaren the mean overwritten, who can overwritten it? only me? (bad coding) or other broadcast or system can overwritten it? thank for support anyway :)

Comment: only make the Log.e if slot != null

Comment: In your call to `getBroadcast()` replace `Intent.FILL_IN_DATA` with `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Replace flowing code
BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode.java

```
public class BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Log.e("BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode", String.valueOf(intent));
        String slot = intent.getExtras().getString("NODE_SLOT");
        Log.e("BroadcastReceiver_CalibrateMode", slot); // NPE ON THIS LINE

        Intent calibrateIntent = new Intent(context, Service_MQTTPush.class);
        calibrateIntent.putExtra("CALIBRATE_MODE",true);
        calibrateIntent.putExtra("NODE_SLOT", slot);

        calibrateIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // SPCIAL CODE

        context.startService(calibrateIntent);
    }
}
```

When calling startActivity, the new activity will live in the same screen stack (context) as the caller. Sometime, the caller may not have an activity context, for instance, starting an activity from **Broadcastreceive.onReceive()** method, or starting an activity from a service. In these cases, call startActivity will cause an exception of "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**", since the new activity does not have a context to live in.

To fix the issue, setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to the intent as follows, then a new context will be created for the new activity.

**myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);**